# For $f '(z) = Bf(z)$, $f(0) = A$, show that $f(z) = e^{(Bz)} A$

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Let $ A,B \in \mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $ f '(z) = Bf(z)$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $f(0) = A$. Show that $f(z) =  e^{(Bz)}A$

Attempt: Write f as $ u + i.v$, then apply that into the derivative equation. Also, I know that I should use if $f '(z) = 0$ for all z, then $f$ is constant but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: @mjw All done, thank you for warning :)

Comment: @mjw So sorry, I always use x instead of z, new in complex analysis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier today, I saw that someone had posted a helpful comment, which for some reason has now been deleted.

The idea is to consider the function $g(z) = e^{-Bz}f(z)$. Since $e^{-Bz}$ and $f(z)$ are holomorphic on $\mathbb C$, $g(z)$ is also holomorphic on $\mathbb C$.

From here on, the steps are:

- Use the chain rule together with the fact that $f'(z) = Bf(z)$ to show that $g'(z) = 0$ everywhere.
- Deduce that $g$ is constant.
- Infer that $f(z) = Ce^{Bz}$ for some constant $C$.
- Fix the constant $C$ using the fact that $f(0) = A$.